# How do I get a list of sold and unsold products in a category sort by Desc order in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I would like to list out all sold and unsold products in a category and then sort by Desc order (based on the sold qty). Is it possible? If yes please let me know do I achieve this. Thanks